# Issue when extruding inset windows on low poly cars

Tags: modeling, extrude

I am following the Imphenzia make 10 cars in 10min tutorial. At https://youtu.be/YALV3HqfdLY?t=600 he insets then extrudes inwards the windows of all 10 cars at the same time.

When I extrude the windows, some look correct while others still have an edge down the middle that has not extruded with the rest of the window. I can't seem to remove it or find a way to have it extrude properly. For reference the cars are have automirror, the windows inset with boundary & individual off.

In photos below, red circles are the issue I'm getting. The green circle is a window that's extruded correctly. Does anyone know what causes this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: send the blend file so we can help

Comment: It looks like there is a gap between the mesh and the mirror. Turn on clipping and bring the vertices to the center so the mirror modifier can weld the mirror and the mesh correctly.

Comment: do you have an inner face?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. I found the vehicles that didn't have clipping turned on were the ones that had the issue. Once I turned on clipping for those cars, the issue went away. I'm embarrassed I didn't check that first! 

I also found that if you have all objects selected and turn clipping on, it won't turn it on for all the objects selected. I had to select each car and turn it on individually. This may be the reason I missed it the first time.